# File Upload in MVC using JQuery Multifile Upload plugin & an iframe

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file, upload

this is really weird. I am able to upload files and save it in database when working locally on my MVC project (using localhost) but when the project is deployed on the server, i am getting directory not found exception (System.IO.DirectoryNotFound). It lists my local file path in the error log on the server.

I am trying to save the file content using Request.Files collection & its contents as a byte array.

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: Can you show the action method, odd that you would have an io exception if your dealing with bytes and a database.

Comment: [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public String Upload(String param)
{ .. }

Comment: Does the input tag need an 'id' and a 'name' attributes? I am using jquery multifile plugin for the upload. The form is submitted to a controller but it's action-target is an iframe. As soon as i submit the upload i can go to the controller method and it all this works fine on localhost but not on the server.

Comment: i am getting a 405 error, what could this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved! It turned out to be an incorrect url in the ACTION attribute of the FORM tag. 
No more HTTP 405 errors & the file is uploaded successfully.